# img listed after selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The selector here `(div.img)` selects all of the divs in the image class right?  What I don't understand is what is the second `img` for?  I've done a little CSS before but I've never come across this syntax.

```
div.img img
{
  display: inline;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Read [the CSS selector API docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) for super basic questions like these, please. You're specifically looking for the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators).

Comment: Most beginners won't immediately consider the significance of whitespace, let alone associate the space character with a combinator, but the link is always a good immediate reference nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second image selects `<img>` tags inside `<div class="img">` tags; the space tells the selector to look at all descendant elements of the `<div>`.

So, if we have

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="foo.png">
</div>
```

The `<img>` tag will have a white border, a 3px margin and be displayed `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

The selector will match any `<img>` elements that are a descendent of a `<div>` element with the CSS class `img`. For example, the following `<img>` tag would be matched by the CSS rule

```
<div class="img">
    <img src="" alt="" /><!-- this img will be matched --> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

div.img denotes name of div's class

So if you have

```
<div class="img">
<img src="image.gif" alt="" />    
</div>
<div>
<img src="image.gif" alt="" />    
</div>
```

then CSS will be applied on the earlier img element, but not on the latter, because that element is not inside div of class img.

Basically, the style will be applied on any img element that is descendant of div element of class img.